# Print syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error

I am new to coding and have a simple problem that I could not figure out.I am using python 2.7.5.

```
>>> z='b'
>>> if 'x'<z:
    print 'Hello'
print 'Mom'

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

(Print is highlighted)

Am I not supposed to get the result Mom? I saw this in the MIT lecture on youtube and tried to do the same as the instructor did but I get this error.Can anyone help me?
Thanks for your time.

Comment: @JBernardo Not in 2.x, though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that you need a newline after `print 'Hello'` in the REPL.

```
>>> if 'x'<'y':
...    print 'Hello'
... print 'Mom'
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    print 'Mom'
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
>>> if 'x'<'y':
...    print 'Hello'
...
Hello
>>>
```